# Image becomes scrollabe with the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I have the code like this for serving the image from 3rd party system:

```
var bbimagebannerfile = "";

document.write("<a href=\"%%__REDIRECT%%\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"" + bbimagebannerfile + "\" border=\"0\" /></a>");
```

This image is positioned at the bottom of the page. What i am trying to do is make this image scroll along with the page once user reaches its position and when the user scrolls upwards then this image becomes static again. Can anyone help me with that ?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet or did some research? If not, try these keywords: `jQuery scroll event` and `window scrollTop`. Check how far the user has scrolled and add/remove a style class to your image accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an example:

```
<div id="fixed-image"></div>
```

If we assume that the HTML above is your content that is being served. You can add this css:

```
#fixed-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

In your case, you can try adding a class property with the styling above.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/df6tmLrg/

Another demo with your javascript:
http://codepen.io/FakeHeal/pen/qEgxKN (codepen, because jsfiddle doesn't allow `document.write`)

```
var bbimagebannerfile = "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/1038697?v=3&s=460";

document.write("<a href=\"%%__REDIRECT%%\" target=\"_blank\" class=\"bottom-fixed\"><img src=\"" + bbimagebannerfile + "\" border=\"0\" width="100" /></a>");
```

And the css:

```
.bottom-fixed {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

UPDATE:
If you use `jQuery`, you can use `.scroll()`:

```
var t =  $("#fixed-image").offset().top; 

$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > t)
    {   
        $("#fixed-image")
        .css('position', 'fixed') //we change the position to fixed
        .css('top',0); // and the top to zero
    } else {
        $("#fixed-image")
        .css('position', 'static') //we change the position to fixed
        .css('top',0); // and the top to zero
    }
});
```

Here's a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/df6tmLrg/2/

Comment: thank you for the answer. I will try to explain the situation. When you open the website, the image, which is loaded with the code i posted is not seen by the user and it is ok. BUT when the user scrolls to down specific amount of pixels the image becomes visible. I want to make this image scrollable along with the page only when user reaches it. It should not be scrollable when the page is opened it should only become scrollable and only to the bottom when user scrolls the page down until reaches the image.